# Javascript regex for upper- and lowercase match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, uppercase, lowercase

I have a text box in my web form. In jQuery I have to verify that the entered text should have at least one lowercase and one uppercase letter. How does the pattern look?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: That searches for a string that starts with 5 characters that may be any of upper or lower case letters.  It doesn't require anything beyond that.  See answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/[a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]/
```

Test here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html (without the `/`)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming ERE:

```
/([A-Z].*[a-z]|[a-z].*[A-Z])/
```

or if you're a purist:

```
/([[:upper:]].*[[:lower:]]|[[:lower:]].*[[:upper:]])/
```

Comment: How good is the POSIX notation compatible to the browsers, do you  know?

Comment: @yunzen - JavaScript supports Perl-compatible regular expressions.  You can [compare flavours](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html) and their capabilities if you like.  If you're asking whether PCRE supports Character Classes, the answer is yes, it does.

Comment: @yunzen Javascript’s native regexes are pretty lame, and not very Perl-compatible at all. The [XRegexp](http://xregexp.com) plug-in goes a long ways toward fixing that.

Comment: @ghoti but my flavor of Chrome RegEx does not support the `:lower:` and `:upper:` POSIX Character Classes. It supports `:Alpha:` and `:alpha:`

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the link. I'll savor this for me.

Comment: Then perhaps [v8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) is not fully PCRE compliant.  `[[:upper:]]` and `[[:lower:]]` POSIX classes are supported by Perl and by extension PCRE, according to [the PCRE man page](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) .

Comment: The Chrome I'm using doesn't seem to support any of  `[[:lower:]]`, `[[:upper:]]`, `[[:alpha:]]`, or `[[:Alpha:]]`

Comment: With the “u” flag, it supports Unicode property escapes like “\p{Lowercase}”.
Ref.: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Unicode_property_escapes

Answer (score 0):

```
       //TODO check Number
       var checkNumber = false
       var matches = currentPassword.match(/\d+/g) ||newPassword.match(/\d+/g) || confirmPassword.match(/\d+/g)  ;
       if (matches != null) {
         checkNumber  = true;
       }

        //TODO check Letter
        var checkLetter = false
        var matchesLetter = currentPassword.match("[a-z\A-Z]") || newPassword.match("[a-z\A-Z]") || confirmPassword.match("[a-z\A-Z]") ;

        if (matchesLetter != null) {
            checkLetter  = true;
        }

        //TODO check upper and lower Letter
        var checkUpperLowerLtr = false
        var matchesUpperLowerLtr = currentPassword.match("[a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]") || newPassword.match("[a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]") || confirmPassword.match("[a-z].*[A-Z]|[A-Z].*[a-z]");

        if (matchesUpperLowerLtr != null) {
            checkUpperLowerLtr  = true;
        }
        //TODO Special
        var checkSpecial = false
        var matchesSpecial = currentPassword.match("/?[#?!@$%^&*-]") || newPassword.match("/?[#?!@$%^&*-]") || confirmPassword.match("/?[#?!@$%^&*-]") ;
        if (matchesSpecial != null) {
            checkSpecial  = true;
        }
```